# safari browser ajax data mapping with server object

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, safari

I have a simple class:

```
public class Person 
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and a MVC controller method:

```
[HttpPut, Route("person/information/{Id}")]
public ActionResult UpdateInformation(int Id,Person person) 
{
   //some processing
}
```

I am calling the controller method via jquery-ajax:

```
var personObj = {
    name: 'SpiderMan',
    age: 25
 };
 $.ajax({
     url: '/person/information/ + $('.form').attr('id'),
     data: JSON.stringify({ person: personObj }),                 
     contentType:'application/json',
     type: 'PUT',
     success: function (resp) {         
     },
     error: function (xhr) {         
     }
 });
```

This works perfectly fine with Chrome and Firefox. I get both the Id and `Person` object in the controller. However, in **Safari browser**(iPhone and Mac) I get only the Id but the properties in the person object received is empty(default values) i.e. the person object is not getting mapped.

If I remove the Id from the url route and parameter like this:

```
[HttpPut, Route("person/information/")]
public ActionResult UpdateInformation(Person person) 
{
   //some processing
}
```

the person object is correctly mapped with the data from ajax request.

What is the reason for the object not being mapped in the first request and how to fix this?

Update: I have attached screenshots for the request parameter
 from browser **Chrome**:

[image: From Chrome]
And request from **Safari**:

[image: From Safari]

Comment: As you state the AJAX works, I assume your misplaced `'` is just a typo in the question? I'd check the request that's being sent to ensure that Safari is correctly adding the data to the body.

Comment: yes that was a typo, I have updated the post and I have attached screenshots for both chrome and safari browser requests